# How to fill the bars on a histogram

Tags: r

[image]I have used the following code for my histogram but the colours are filling the border, but I would like it to fill the bar and have the borders black,

```
ggplot(user_col, aes(x=Nscore, colour=User)) + geom_histogram(position = "stack") +   scale_fill_manual(
values = c("User" = "red", "NonUser" = "blue"))
```

Comment: Instead of `colour = User`, try `fill = User`

Comment: The legend has the correct colour but the histogram is fully grey

Comment: I have tried using dput() to copy the file but its not bringing up summary() so I can't share the file

Comment: Are you able to show a small sample of your data?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `fill=...` option

```
ggplot(user_col, aes(x=Nscore, colour=User, fill=User)) + 
  geom_histogram(position = "stack") +  
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("User" = "red", "NonUser" = "blue"))
```

Comment: that's not worked either

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).